# Why is this notification code not working?

Tags: android, notifications

This is what I have written in android studio. Its not working.  No notification pops up.

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent i_mainActivity=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent p_mainActivity=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i_mainActivity, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification_popup=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("An Alarm is going on")
            .setContentText("Click to stop")
            .setContentIntent(p_mainActivity)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    int id=001;
    notificationManager.notify(id,notification_popup.build());
```

Comment: Please explain what "Its not working" means. What are your symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an icon, which is a required components in notifications. Android will not show your notification if it is missing any required components.

In particular, [the Notifications documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) says:

> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()

Comment: Was missing the small icon. Thank you:)